# I will host an event outside(,) whether it rains or not. - comma or not?

Tags: conjunctions

**Example 1**

> I will host an event outside whether it rains or not.

**Example 2**

> I will host an event outside, whether it rains or not.

When do we add a comma to before "whether"?

I still don't get the whole essential/non-essential thing.

Comment: It's discretionary. It is unnecessary but does no harm.

Comment: The comma just reflects a pause in speech. So if you think you'd pause there yourself[,] write the comma. Otherwise, *don't*.

Comment: Punctuation is optional. With this kind of adjunct, some people prefer to set it off with punctuation, while others don't.